# \pdfpkresolution=250

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pdf

Is it possible to put \pdfpkresolution=250 ?

The only possible values I can assign are 300 and 100 but not any number between them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pdfmapfile{-pdftex.map}
\pdfpkresolution=250

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\left \{ N\ |\ N\trianglelefteq G \right \}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the minus sign in -pdftex.map? Without it an arbitrary resolution appears to work for me.

Comment: With the minus sign I obtain fuzzy font, that's what I want. And with \pdfpkresolution=250 I'd like to reduce the resolution of the font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no available modes for 250 dpi; there are some for 240dpi, for instance `canonlbp`. You need to set both the resolution and the mode; since you want to get an awful output, I guess that 10 dpi difference is not relevant.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\pdfmapfile{-pdftex.map}
\pdfpkresolution=240
\pdfpkmode{canonlbp}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

$\left \{ N\ |\ N\trianglelefteq G \right \}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The list of available modes is available in `modes.mf`, which you can look at with

```bsh
less $(kpsewhich modes.mf)
```